# Indefinite integral of $\frac{\arctan x}{x^2+1}$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

**EDIT:** I was studying from a site that uses really ambiguous notation so I misread $\arctan\ (x)^2$ as $\arctan\ (x^2)$. Now I can see why the integral is actually $\frac{1}{2} \arctan^2\ x + c $. Thanks to everyone who answered and corrected me!

Why is $$\int\frac{\arctan\ x}{x^2+1} dx=\frac{1}{2}\arctan(x^2)+c$$
instead of $\int u\ du$ where $u=\arctan\ x$ and $du=\frac{1}{x^2+1} dx$, thus $$\begin{align} &\int\frac{\arctan\ x}{x^2+1} dx=\int \arctan\ x\ dx \\
&x\ \arctan\ x-\int \frac{x}{x^2+1}\ dx \\
&x\ \arctan\ x -\frac{1}{2}\ln(x^2+1)+c\end{align}$$

Is there something I'm not getting? I'd like to see the steps for the correct calculation so I can better understand it. Thanks!

Comment: Using $x=\tan u$ will be a shortcut

Comment: as pointed out in answers, you have incorrectly typed; it is not $x^2,$ it is $(\arctan x)^2.$ This is often written $\arctan^2 x;$ it is just a convenient usage.

Answer (score 2):

instead of $\int u\ du$ where $u=\arctan\ x$ and $du=\frac{1}{x^2+1} dx$, thus $$\int\frac{\arctan\ x}{x^2+1} dx=\int u du= \frac12u^2+C=\frac12(\arctan x)^2+C$$

Comment: Oh, so I was only forgetting $\int x\ dx=\frac{x^2}{2}$! This clears it up and it's a much nicer calculation than what I was trying to do, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Notice that

$$\int f'f=\frac12 f^2+c$$
so the answer for your antiderivative is $\frac12(\arctan x)^2+c$.

Comment: This is a good explanation, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Your notation may be a bit off?

Doing the $u$-substitution gives

$$\int \frac{\arctan x}{1+x^2}dx = \int u\text{ }du = \frac{u^2}{2} + C = \frac{(\arctan x)^2}{2} + C.$$

Note that $(\arctan x)^2 \neq \arctan \left(x^2\right)$.

Comment: You're actually right, the site I was studying from uses really ambiguous parentheses and I misread it. Everything makes more sense now.